# Undefined Symbol Error when using thrust::max_element

Tags: cuda, cmake, thrust, nvcc

I am working on a CUDA C++ project that uses separable compilation, and I am having some trouble getting a thrust function to compile.

The project builds with no problem until the following function call is added.

```
thrust::device_ptr<float> max_int = thrust::max_element(
    thrust::device_ptr<float>(dev_temp_intensity_buffer),
    thrust::device_ptr<float>(dev_temp_intensity_buffer + INT_BUF_SIZE);
```

As said, I get the build error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __fatbinwrap_66_tmpxft_00006db0_00000000_18_cuda_device_runtime_compute_61_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37 referenced in function __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_66_tmpxft_00006db0_00000000_18_cuda_device_runtime_compute_61_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37 visualize   C:\Users\13\Google Drive\WireMeshOT Rafael\CUDA\simulator\build\src\visualize_intermediate_link.obj 1
```

The funny thing is that this other thrust function call compiles just fine:

```
thrust::exclusive_scan(thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>(dev_ray_alive),
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>(dev_ray_alive + NRAYS),
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>(dev_scanned_alive_rays));
```

Obs1: `dev_temp_intensity_buffer` is a float device pointer, and I am including  `thrust/extrema.h` and `thrust/device_ptr.h`.

Obs2: I am using CMake to configure the build. The relevant CMake code excerpts are shown below.

```
SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -rdc=true -D_FORCE_INLINES) 
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -arch=compute_52  -code=sm_52 -lcudart -lcudadevrt -lcuda)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -Xptxas -v)

cuda_add_executable(
 project 
 file1.cu
  ...)

target_link_libraries (project glut glew)
```

Comment: Looks similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704204/linking-cuda-plain-c-code-undefined-reference-to-fatbinwrap-66-tmpxft-e

Comment: @JaredHoberock Yes it does. I've added -lcudadevrt to the nvcc flags and I have also tried using `target_link_libraries (visualize utils cuda_utils glut glew ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})` without any success. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Does the problem occur independently from your CMake build? Are you able to link together a program manually from the command line? Can you post a small reproducer program that demonstrates the problem so that others can try on their systems?

Comment: @JaredHoberock your investigation would have been useful but the problem has been solved. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

The linking problem was due to the fact that `cudadevrt` library was missing. The catch is that only adding `-lcudadevrt` to the `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` was not enough!

The problem goes away when linking the CUDA runtime device library to the CMake target as shown below:

`target_link_libraries(project glut glew ${CUDA_cudadevrt_LIBRARY})`

Obs1: the `CUDA_cudadevrt_LIBRARY` variable is only made available on CMake versions above 3.7.2. Adding the line `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)` is a good idea.

Obs2: linking only to `CUDA_LIBRARIES` as below does solve the issue only if you are using a CMake version above 3.7.2. On lower versions this variable exist but does not contain `cudadevrt` library.

`target_link_libraries(project glut glew ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})`