# Undefined reference error to 'fatbinwrap' - CUDA/C++

Tags: c++, dll, cuda, g++, nvcc

I'm facing with a problem with making .dll from .cu files with Cuda/C++.
There is a .o (C++ object file) compiled by nvcc with some parameters:

```
nvcc -dlink -o kernel.o -rdc=true kernel.cu
```

and passing options to the g++ compiler:

```
g++ -shared kernel.o -o kernel.dll -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\lib\x64" -lcudart -lcuda -lcudadevrt
```

However, I got the following error like below:

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:\Program Files\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: kernel.o:(.text$mn+0x160): undefined reference to `__fatbinwrap_......_kernel_cu_add'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Cuda toolkit version is 12.0 and the g++ one is 12.2.0, which runs on Windows 10.

Here is my code:

**kernel.cu**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "kernel.cuh"

extern "C" __global__ void add(int n, float *a, float *b, float *sum)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

extern "C" __host__ void launchKernel()
{
    std::cout << "function called" << std::endl; //DEBUG CODE
    //Here launch kernel code.
}
```

**kernel.cuh**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __global__ void add(int n, float *a, float *b, float *sum);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __host__ void launchKernel();
```

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886052/cuda-c-linking-error-undefined-reference-to) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704204/linking-cuda-plain-c-code-undefined-reference-to-fatbinwrap-66-tmpxft-e) but there is still a compile error. I'm beginner at Cuda/C++ so my code might looks like funny. To make .dll file with Cuda/C++, what should I do something else? Thank you.

Comment: You can’t use g++ on windows with CUDA. Only the MS C++ toolchain is supported

Comment: Opened in Visual Studio and set up buildpath, the project was compiled successfully. Thanks for your help.